# how to find factorial of a really big number

Tags: java, time-complexity, biginteger, factorial

I am trying to find out the output of this question but its not working, when n goes to 10^6 as it's taking a lot of time 
is there any way to find it quicker?

find the trailing zeros of factorial of n
where 
1<= n <=10^6

here is my code :

```
     public static void main(String[] args) {
            test t=new test();                 
            Scanner input =new Scanner(System.in);
            int m=input.nextInt();               
            String x=t.factorial(m).toString();
            int count=0;
            for(int i=x.length()-1;i>0;i--){
                    if(x.charAt(i)=='0')
                            count++;
                    else{
                            i=0;
                    }
            }
            System.out.println(count);

    }

    BigInteger factorial(int num){
            BigInteger temp = BigInteger.ONE;
            for(int i=1;i<=num;i++)
                    temp = temp.multiply(new BigInteger(i + ""));
            return temp;
    }
```

Comment: Why are you converting the number to a string and then to `BigInteger`?

Comment: to calculate index position faster

Comment: I mean why `new BigInteger(i + "")` and not `new BigInteger(i)`? There's no index position involved there.

Comment: it doesn't make any difference anyway

Comment: What you probably are after is more a math question than programming. Did you google for e.g. "shortcut to calculate factorial"?

Comment: yes i did but not found any useful stuffs

Comment: Have a look here: http://www.luschny.de/math/factorial/FastFactorialFunctions.htm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Find the trailing zeros of factorial of `n` where `1 <= n <= 10^6`

The ending zeros are limited by factors of 5. The number of multiples of `5` that are at most `n` is `n/5` (with integer-division), but this doesn't count the repeated factors in multiples of `25, 125, ....`. To get those, divide `n` by 5 and do a recursive call.
[<sup>source</sup>](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/79763/52210)

Here an example implementation in Java:

```
int trailingZerosOfFactorial(int number){
  if(number == 0){
    return 0;
  }
  int nrIntegerDividedByFive = number/5;
  return nrIntegerDividedByFive + trailingZerosOfFactorial(nrIntegerDividedByFive);
}
```

[**Try it online.**](https://tio.run/##lZExb4MwEIX3/IobQVWDQQUVRSxVEqlD1SFbq6pywEGXGoPsAzWq@O3UBKYQBgZbOt@9796Tz7zhj@fsp@tSyY2BN47qbwVgiBOmgIqANEeJKv8QujTvpz1PqdTIpdM3VV0chXZ7CQCenKGGJAE2PgJoQbVWwDbXuh1Ge61@VSRyobfYYCayl8seGwHJCPXCQTDKZ6Yf5v3dV7g9tV3Zq6qP0mYcozYlZlDY@M6BtMUB17n5/BpTHC6GRLEua1pXtktSObN7fdfdgOfB7rcSKYkM2GJEeIvwl7tg7BYSPC2mRFE0sRKFizEB8yeckAXLQ30zxvozjRbH8fP1Z9uu@wc)

With this implementation, we avoid the actual calculation of the factorial, which is the main bottleneck. Therefore, this calculates `n = 1_000_000` in about 1.5 sec (resulting in `249998`).